# number_in_month exercise (Error in SML function to build a list of integers from a list of tuples)

Tags: tuples, pattern-matching, sml, smlnj

```
val test1 = [(1,5,3),(3,5,2),(3,4,5)]

fun number_in_month dates_and_month  =
    case dates_and_month of
        (x,y,z)::xs' => y :: number_in_month xs'
```

This code produces the following error when I run in the REPL with test1:

uncaught exception Match [nonexhaustive match failure]
  raised at: hw1pm.sml:28.49

Any clue why?

Answer (score 2):

It did not know what do when the list was empty.

Working code:

```
fun number_in_month dates_and_month  =
    case dates_and_month of
        [] => []
        | (x,y,z)::xs' => y :: number_in_month xs'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I've tried to make this answer more helpful while preserving the observation that this is probably the most asked SML question on StackOverflow. A total list of the times this question was asked: [1st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348568), [2nd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409502), [3rd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429734), [4th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431526), [5th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470895), [6th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508839), [7th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331899), [8th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388391), [9th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398097), [10th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452116), [11th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600814), [12th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925971), [13th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150427), [14th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204390), [15th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60157435) and [16th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158621) (not counting this post).

Rather than to answer this question again, a curated version of those are here:

- [1st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348568), [2nd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409502), [6th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508839), [12th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925971) struggle with recursion and infinite recursion. Some attempts include the use of the function `null`, and others include pattern matching. I'd go with the recommendation to use pattern matching.
- [3rd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429734), [4th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431526), [5th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470895), [7th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331899), [13th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150427), [14th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204390) provide **a lot** of insight into the general structure of this function. You'll probably learn a bunch more than you asked for by just reading those answers, and since they cover a lot of elementary subjects in the context of a function you're actively working with, this may be very worthwhile.
- [10th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452116) deals with using a mutable reference, so stay away from that one unless you're about to make that same mistake!
- [11th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600814) doesn't actually ask anything, but the author says they have this exercise and then kind of stops dead in their tracks. There's a lesson here and I'm not going to be the one to figure it out.
- [8th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388391), [9th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398097), [15th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60157435) and [16th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158621) appear to address syntax errors.

---

Questions asked on this matter subsequent to this answer: [17th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449439) (missing `else`).