# what does "syntax error found at EOF" means and why am i getting it for this recursive function?

Tags: syntax-error, sml, smlnj

I'm getting the error in SMLNJ:

`Error: syntax error found at EOF`

what does this means?
The function that seems to be causing the error is the following.

```
fun number_in_month (dates : int*int*int list, month : int) = 
           if null dates
           then 0
           else if #2 (hd dates) = month
           then number_in_month(tl dates, month) + 1
```

It is supposed to take a list of dates (`int*int*int` list) and a month (`int`) and returns how many dates in the list are in the given month.
Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: You're missing an `else`.

Comment: Take a look at [some other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsml%5D+number_in_month) about this exercise.

Comment: See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402276).

Comment: @SimonShine Thank you. I should have tried to search more in deep before asking.